# Graphs with all vertices having more neighbors than 2nd order neighbors

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, conjectures

This is the conjecture that inspired my question:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_neighborhood_problem

For any vertex $v$, let $N(v)$ be the set of vertices adjacent to $v$ and let $N^2(v)$ the set 2nd order neighbors, thus all vertices that have a distance of exactly 2 relative to $v$. The conjecture concerns directed graphs, but I was interested in undirected simple graphs with each vertex having strictly more neighbors than second order neighbors. A  basic example would be a graph of 4 vertices, completely connected except for one edge.

I believe such graphs are exactly the ones that have the following characteristic: for each vertex $v$,  more than half of all possible 2-step walks starting from $v$ have an endpoint in $N(v)$

So far I haven't encountered a counter example but neither can I prove it, it's somewhat intuitive but not completely. Would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

For an extreme counterexample, take $G = K_{n,n}$, the complete bipartite graph with $n$ vertices on each side. Here, $|N(v)|=n$ and $|N^2(v)| = n-1$ for all $v$, and *none* of the two-step walks from any vertex $v$ end up in $N(v)$.

Comment: Wow. That's extreme indeed, well spotted. You think the other direction might be actually correct or am I way off? Any other ideas for counter examples?

Comment: I think where all the easy-to-find examples are coming from are graphs with a large minimum degree (so $|N(v)| > |N^2(v)|$ because so many vertices are in $N(v)$ we don't have as many left for $|N^2(v)|$). I don't see why there should be a connection to how many $2$-step walks end up in $N(v)$.

Comment: Well you say you want a large minimum degree ( for every vertex thus). But then you will also get large $N^2(v)$ unless you route a part of these paths back to $N(v)$. You're counterexample surpassed this logic completely but I feel like it really was one in a kind in doing that.

Comment: No adjacent vertices can have a degree twice as high. That would really mess everything up as far as I can think of, agree?

Comment: The other way to get small $N^2(v)$ is for the neighbors of vertices in $N(v)$ to have a lot of overlap. (And, yes: if $v$ is adjacent to $w$ and $\deg(w) \ge 2 \deg(v)$, then the neighbors of $w$ not in $N(v)$ are on their own enough to make $N^2(v)$ as large as $N(v)$.)

Comment: So basically only cliques with two or more  shared vertices I think.  More cliques overlapping would require more vertices shared. That or the complete bipartite graph. Is that about right you think?

Comment: Well, here is an interesting sparse example: start with a cycle $C_a$. Replace every vertex by a clique $K_b$, and every edge between two vertices of the cycle by all $b^2$ possible edges between the two cliques. For any vertex $v$, we have $|N(v)| = 3b-1$ and $|N^2(v)| = 2b$, so if $b \ge 2$ then $|N(v)| > |N^2(v)|$. (Here, the condition does hold that about $\frac79$ of the two-step walks from $v$ end in $N(v)$, though.)

Comment: Which is basically $a$ cliques of size $2b$ and each vertex in exactly 2 cliques  right?  I'll try to find a way to define these  clique structures. Maybe they do actually abide the two step walk claim I made earlier, that would be pretty sweet.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142310/discussion-between-bob-langefeld-and-misha-lavrov).